# multiple delete row from same table prior to content and sub-row

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

```
query = function to mysqli_query
checkinfo = function to check whether column consist data exist or not.
d_id = department id(primary key for table department)
d_pid = department parent id
```

i try to delete row from table. but before deleting those row, i want to eliminate all row that use current-to-be delete row as their d_pid. There will be 4 level of structure.

below, i try to execute command, by checking content first. if content exist, mysql suppose to delete sub-row first. but if sub-row also have child row, mysql suppose to delete it lower row prior to upper.

```
for($x1 = checkInfo("d_id","department","WHERE d_pid='$selectedID'");!empty($x1);$count1++){
    for($x2 = checkInfo("d_id","department","WHERE d_pid='$x1'");!empty($x2);$count2++){
        for($x3 = checkInfo("d_id","department","WHERE d_pid='$x2'");!empty($x3);$count3++){
            query($con,"DELETE FROM department WHERE d_id='$x3' OR d_pid='$x3'");
            // echo "3</br>";
        }   
        query($con,"DELETE FROM department WHERE d_id='$x2' OR d_pid='$x2'");
        // echo "2</br>";
    }
    query($con,"DELETE FROM department WHERE d_id='$x1' OR d_pid='$x1'");
    // echo "1</br>";   
}
$sql = "DELETE FROM department WHERE d_id='$selectedID' OR d_pid='$selectedID'";
$result = query($con,$sql);
```

i got multiple error. is there any other way to do this?

Comment: This is exactly what [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) with cascading deletion actions were designed for.

Comment: OMG!!!!!!!!!!!! silly me. i can assign own table as foreign? ty eggyal